# The type constructor is not yet completely defined

Tags: ocaml, strong-typing, typing

Here's my simplified code :

```
type t1 = [ `A of t2]
and t2 = [ `B | t1 ]
```

I know that in this case I don't need the "and" because my types don't need mutual definition, but in the real world I need it.
Why doesn't that work ? I can make it work by doing

```
and t2 = [`B | `C of t1]
```

but now I lose all the interest of my polymorphic variants and I'll just switch to normal variants.

Is there any way I can do this ?

Answer (score 3):

In definition of t2 you are trying to "extend" type t1 which is not completely defined at this point (as it requre t2 in `A branch).

If you want to "emulate" recursive ordinary data types (but using polymorphic variants instead) you should use all references to mutually-recursive types under data constructor.
Your example in this case may look like this:

```
type t1 = [ `A of t2 ]
and t2 = [ `B | `C of t1 ]
```

Note also that in Ocaml construction [ `B | t1 ] does **not** mean extending polymorphic row with another row - it is just type synonym substitution.

Comment: I know that, I wrote it in my question :). I don't understand the difference between extending the type and having a synonym. Doesn't seem to make any difference in ocaml.

Comment: And I still don't understand why it works with the `C but not without it.

Comment: @double_squeeze what you expect from compiler in this case? Ocaml tries to "unfold" it to [ A of [ B | A of [ B | A of ... ]]] which is infinite, so this error. With `C it can unfold to [ A of [ B | C of 'a ] as 'a ] which is perfectly OK.

Comment: Why not [ A of [ B | A of 'a ] as 'a ] ? I mean it's really the same thing, at least it seems to me like it is. I don't get why the compiler can get it in one case but not in the other.